# Когда вызывается оператор преобразования типов?

Tags: преобразование, c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class three_d {
    int x, y, z;
public:
    three_d(int a, int b, int c) {x=a; y=b, z=c; }
    three_d operator+(three_d op2);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, three_d &obj);
    operator int() {return x*y*z;}
};
ostream &operator<< (ostream &stream, three_d &obj)
{
    stream << obj.x << ", ";
    stream << obj.y << ", ";
    stream << obj.z << endl;
    return stream;
}
three_d three_d::operator+ (three_d op2)
{
    x+=op2.x;
    y+=op2.y; 
    z+=op2.z; 
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    three_d a(1, 2, 3), b(2, 3, 4);
    cout << a << b;
    cout << b+100 << endl; //31 line
    cout << a+b << endl; // 32
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В 31 строчке объект `b` приводится к `int`, потому что справа значение int, но зачем в 32 строчке привидении работает после того как выполнился `operator+`? Ведь тут два объекта с обоих сторон, почему тогда вызывается функция преобразования или как оно там называется, да ещё и в конце?

Comment: @mzarb: Ну, const распространяется только на аргумент, так что вне функции он никак не подействует. Кроме того, компилятор сам ничего не делает, он лишь следует вашим указаниям, которые он понимает в соответствии со стандартом. (Так что это не он присваивает, это вы.)

Comment: @VladD, то есть возвращаемое значение не относится к области видимости функции и когда будет выход из функции, то временный объект не будет освобождаться или уничтожатся, так как он уже не часть функции, после того как его передали? К примеру в этом коде [http://ideone.com/v5BT6R][1] временный объект возвращается по ссылке и при выводе какие-то странные значения, так как все данные видимо разрушились вместе со стеком.


  [1]: http://ideone.com/v5BT6R

Comment: @mzarb: Угу, так и есть: возвращается ссылка на объект в стеке, который, понятно, сразу же умирает после того, как функция отработает. Вот такой вариант более правильный: http://ideone.com/iTkjmB

---
Ещё более правильный вариант: http://ideone.com/lbD7Y9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ваш объект суммы не lvalue. Для него нужно [`const`](http://ideone.com/Mb0tOI):

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, const three_d &obj);
```

Без `const` `cout << a+b` трактуется не как

```
operator<<(cout, a+b) // ostream &stream, three_d &obj
```

а как

```
operator<<(cout, (int)(a+b)) // ostream &stream, const int& i
```

Объект, не являющийся lvalue, [не](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6967989/276994) [может](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6967980/276994) быть использован с не-const-ссылкой.

---

Смотрите, что происходит.

Компилятор пытается понять, что же ему вызывать для выражения `cout << a + b`.

Поскольку `a + b` -- не lvalue, то `ostream &operator<< (ostream &stream, three_d &obj)` отпадает. Раз так, компилятор смотрит, как он может преобразовать аргументы, чтобы другие функции подошли.

Компилятор пробует известные ему операторы `<<`. Когда он пробует `ostream &operator<< (ostream &stream, const int &i)`, он видит, что можно использовать этот оператор, если преобразовать второй аргумент в `int`. Поскольку вы предоставили преобразование, этот вариант проходит.

---

Отдельно от темы: ваш оператор сложения -- ужас! Вы модифицируете первое слагаемое!

Представьте себе, если бы сложение чисел вело себя так:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7;
int c = a + b;
// здесь внезапно a == 12
```

Ваш код ведёт себя именно так.

Вот как надо:

```
three_d three_d::operator+ (three_d op2)
{
    return three_d(x + op2.x, y + op2.y, z + op2.z);
}
```

Comment: Отличный разбор. И вопрос хорош. Наглядная демонстрация того ужаса, которым является С++.

Comment: @avp: это да, C++ слишком сильно озабочен подробностями семантики копирования.

Comment: @VladD, а ноги-то (IMHO, конечно) растут из "благого" желания переопределения *операций*.

Вот в Java, например, этого нет, и язык реально проще.

Comment: @avp: и ещё, как мне кажется, из лозунга "вы не платите за то, чего не просили" -- что выливается в чрезмерно общую функциональность (современные компиляторы всё ещё не умеют оптимизировать STL так, как это можно было бы сделать вручную, не говоря уже про boost).

Comment: @VladD, А зачем нужна константная ссылка для rvalue, в данном случае для временного объекта, можно поподробней, а то везде пишется просто о защите? И временный объект - rvalue, потому что он временный и если бы можно было присвоить ему значения, то было бы UB? А что тогда делает константная ссылка, копирует временный объект, чтобы к нему гарантированно был доступ после выхода из функции? Если так, то впервые слышу о таком свойстве const, я думал что оно просто запрещает модифицировать то, после чего указанно, но не то что ещё и создает копию.

Comment: @mzarb: Нет, что вы, никаких копий не создаётся. Идея вот в чём (если я правильно понимаю). Давайте посмотрим на такой упрощённый код:

    void Change(int& x) { x += 1; }
    void Print(const int& x) { cout << x; }

    Change(2 + 3);
    Print(2 + 3);

Вызов `Change(2 + 3);` лишён смысла, потому что в отсутствие const значение выражения _может_ быть изменено, и нет никакой возможности увидеть результат этого изменения. Поэтому такой код, судя по всему, ошибочен. Вот стандарт и решил не пропускать такой код.

...

Comment: @mzarb: ...

Вызов `Print(2 + 3);`, напротив, вполне нормален: вы обещаете не менять значение, т. к. аргумент `Print` -- const. То есть логической ошибки нету.

Если бы мы написали

    int x = 2 + 3;
    Change(x);

-- это снова-таки нормально, потому что теперь аргумент -- lvalue, его можно проверить после изменения.

Comment: @VladD, а каким образом можно было бы изменить временный объект суммы в вопросе, если бы он работал без const?

Comment: @mzarb: Мало ли как. Например:

    ostream &operator<< (ostream &stream, three_d &obj)
    {
        obj.x += 1;
        stream << obj.x << ", ";
        stream << obj.y << ", ";
        stream << obj.z << endl;
        return stream;
    }


Если бы было const, код `obj.x += 1;` бы не откомпилировался.

Компилятор не знает, что вы там делаете с объектом. Если нету const, он считает, что вы потенциально можете его (объект) изменить.

Comment: @VladD, то есть ставя const, изменить значение не могу не только я, но и компилятор при выходе из функции не сможет изменить или записать  что-то на место этого временного объекта?